# Partitioning the range of a function by numbers $a_i$ such that each set $\{x \mid f(x) = a_i\}$ has measure zero

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $f \in C_b(S)$ (set of all bounded and continuous functions) and $\mu$ be a measure on $S$ where $S$ is a complete separable metric space. Then a book (Probability Theory by Borkar) claims that for a given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N \geq 1$ and $a_0 < a_1 < a_2<\dots <a_N$ such that

(a) $\|f\| -1 = a_0 < a_1 < a_2<\dots <a_N = \|f\| + 1$

(b) $\mu(\{x | f(x) = a_i\})=0$ for all $i$ and

(c) $a_i - a_{i-1} \leq \epsilon$, $1 \leq i \leq N$ .

I am not understanding how can he claim point (b) for a general $\mu$.

Then he claims $\bigcup_{i=1}^{N} \{x|a_{i-1} \leq f(x) \lt a_i\}=S$.

$\|f\| = \sup_x|f(x)|$

Comment: Is $\mu(S)$ finite (probably equal to $1$)? The reason this is possible: there can be only countably many numbers $a$ such that the set $\{x : f(x)=a\}$ has positive measure. Otherwise their (disjoint) union would have infinite measure.

Comment: @Behaviour: OK. But, how what is the meaning of (1). It does not cover the whole range of $f$.

Comment: (a) could have a type, maybe the left side should be $-\|f\|-1$.

Comment: @Behaviour: hmm, looks like so.

Comment: @Behaviour: Also, what is the reason of $-1$ and $+1$ in (1) ?

Comment: Just to have a little room around. If you don't add $1$, then the union does not capture the points where $f(x)=\|f\|$ because of the strict inequality. But most likely it has something to do with the way the proof goes later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think we established that:

1. The measure space, being finite, [cannot contain an uncountable family of disjoint sets of positive measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/8085/147263). Therefore, there are only countably many values of $a$ that have to be avoided when choosing $a_i$.
2. The inequality in (a) should probably be 
   $$ -\|f\| -1 = a_0 < a_1 < a_2<\dots <a_N = \|f\| + 1$$
3. Every value of $f$ falls strictly between  $-\|f\| -1$ and  $\|f\| + 1$, hence the sets $\bigcup_{i=1}^{N} \{x|a_{i-1} \leq f(x) \lt a_i\} $ cover $S$.

Comment: I think the left side -1 is not needed.

Comment: It's not needed for what is written in your question. But it does no harm there. And many the author had some use for it later?